# Spring @Autowired on all setter in a class

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, annotations, autowired

Is possible to specify that all setter should be autowired with one annotation?

This is my class:

```
@Component
public class MyClass {

    private static Bean1 bean1;
    //...
    private static BeanN beanN;

    public static Bean1 getBean1() {
        return bean1;
    }
    @Autowired
    public void setBean1(Bean1 bean1) {
        MyClass.bean1 = bean1;
    }
    //...
    public static BeanN getBeanN() {
        return beanN;
    }
    @Autowired
    public void setBeanN(BeanN beanN) {
        MyClass.beanN = beanN;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There is no such built-in annotation. Also, Spring doesn't care that your method is to be interpreted as a bean mutator (a setter). Any method can be annotated with [`@Autowired`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) and Spring will try to invoke it with the appropriate arguments.

---

Since the whole point of Spring is dependency injection, there's no reason for you to have `static` fields. Just inject the bean where you need it.

Comment: Yep, an alterative could be to set all properties in a single method (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17353158/autowired-any-method-name-with-any-number-of-arguments). Ideally the constructor, and variables (ideally) should be final, and not static too :)